# ssh -Tv authenticates and lists the right git repo, but I can't clone

Tags: git, command-line, ssh, amazon-ec2, bitbucket

I use Bitbucket, and I'm trying to set up a new EC2 AMI (Amazon Linux) for a new deployment.  I'm testing out pulling down source code from our git repo at Bitbucket using a deployment key.  When I run...

```
ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org
```

... it responds with a much longer version of the following but the gist is, it authenticates ...

```
authenticated via a deploy key.
You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
This deploy key has read access to the following repositories:
myacct/myrepo: deploy-key -- deploy-key
```

But then when I run...

```
sudo git clone git@bitbucket.org:myacct/myrepo.git
```

... I'm getting the response ...

```
Cloning into 'myrepo'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, any hints?

---

**EDIT:** 
I should add, I've got the following defined in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host bitbucket.org
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/deployment.pem
StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

And the deployment.pem is indeed my Private Key for which I used to generate the deployment key (public) that is stored up at Bitbucket.

Answer (score 0):

Damn, it was as simple as **NOT** using `sudo` when calling the `git clone...` command.  Not sure why `sudo` would prevent it from running, but sure enough removing it worked like a charm.